# Problems with Deployment Slots in Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I Have an App Service published and I have created 2 Deployment Slots to test an update. One of them with the configuration cloned and another without clone the configuration

[image]

When I test my local project works fine

[image]

The publisehd api works fine

[image]

But when I publish in any of the slots I get 500 internal server error

[image]

And I don´t see any error log here

[image]

I don't know where I can see some more information about this problem that I don't understand

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: You can try checking app event log if you go to "Advanced tools" blade in your app service settings, clicking the "Go" link, then opening the debug console and navigating to the `LogFiles` directory. You also can try adding application insights integration to your app, that might help surfacing some issues.

Answer (score -1):

*Create an API and publish it with the deployment slots, one with cloned configuration and other without cloned.*
[image]
*Below is the response in local environment.*
[image]

*Below is the response from API after deployed in Azure*
[image]
*Below is the response in the local browser from API which is published azure *
*We need to use the* `"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"`  and `value "d*****e"`

[image]